# Spawn an instance of a library object at a random X position in the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I am new to ActionScript 3.0, and am just trying to make a simple game where an instance of a MovieClip falls from the top of the screen at a random X position.

The plan: 
Create like 4-5 instances of the MovieClip, spawn them above the stage at random X, and have them fall. They should loop back to the top once they are off-screen, and re-randomize the X-coordinate when they do so.

The problem:
I need help on the scripting, because I have pretty much no idea how to do this. I know how to make my buttons go to the scenes I want, and how to make the basket that will catch said MovieClips move along the x axis... that's about it.

Thanks!!

If I left any info out, let me know.

Comment: Do they fall with same speed? Do they spawn in different time? Do you need restrict max number of falling items on the screen?

Comment: Just the 4-5 items looping, constant speed for now. For the game's purposes, maybe start at a certain speed but then increase later on, but that would be a static variable I would change based on the score,  (after 100 points difficulty increases) but I'm pretty sure I know how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do (in case you haven't done this yet) is to export it for ActionScript.

**Step 1:** Right click on your movie clip in the library. Click **properties**. Check the "**Export for ActionScript**" checkbox. If you can't see it you might need to click **Advanced** first. Assign a class name to your movieclip. You can leave the base class as is unless you are extending another class instance. Click **OK**.

**Step 2**: Right click on a frame in a timeline where you want to generate the movieclip. Click **Actions**. Assuming we named the class **MyMovieClip**, this block of code will add an instance of that movie clip into the stage:

```
var mc:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip() // creates a instance of the movieclip, i.e, an object
addChild(mc);                          // adds the movie clip to the upper left corner of the stage relative to the movie clip's registration point
```

That's basically how you add a movieclip to the stage. To add it at a random **x location** in the stage, you need to make use of **mc**'s **x** and **y** fields and the **Math.random()** function.

**Math.random()** generates a pseudo-random Number n between 0 and 1 (0 <= n < 1), e.g., 0.1232... Since you might be needing a value greater or equal to 0, you will need to multiply the result to a certain integer value. Example:

```
var result:Number = Math.random() * 100  // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < 100
```

Now since you want an x value relative to the stage, you must multiply **Math.random()** with the stage's width instead.

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth // returns a number between n, where 0 <= n < stage.stageWidth
```

**Step 3:** Simply set the x value of the movieclip using the pseudo-random number generated before adding it to the stage.

```
mc.x = randomX;
```

If you want it to animate by itself upon entering the stage, you will need to study event handling in AS3. See [this link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/event_handling_as3.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Would I just check mc.y for being off the stage, the  call the whole thing again?

Comment: You can check if a movie clip is off the stage using its `x` or `y` field.  `(mc.y > stage.stageHeight || mc.y < 0)` would work for your requirement. Note that the `x` and `y` fields are relative to your movie clip's registration point. See http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/xymove.htm